# test java regex in php

Tags: java, php, android, regex

we are developing an android app and using some regex in that. I want to create some bulk unit tests at the server side to detect any issues before major releases.. for this purpose i need to mimic the java regex matching behavior on server side where i don't have access to java. I am coding in php. Is there any way to mimic java regex behavior without executing java or if there is any third party api (either free or paid) which I can call to get the result of java regex..

Comment: I'm always fond of using https://regex101.com/#javascript. If you know what you're looking for that should help you to format it and/or get the bulk of the guess and check done.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a function called `preg_match` that will allow you to test a string against a regex pattern.  Re-use the Java regex patterns and do something like this:

```
$yourPattern = '~^\d+$~'; // example pattern matching digits
if (preg_match($yourPattern, $someString)) {
    print 'Valid';
}
```

> preg_match — Perform a regular expression match
>
> **Usage**
>
> *int preg_match ( string $pattern , string $subject [, array &$matches [, int $flags = 0 [, int $offset = 0 ]]] )*
>
> **Source**
>
> http://php.net/preg_match

Comment: my problem is that i need to exactly mimic the java regex behavior, it is a qa activity of regular expressions which are to be eventually used in a java device. thanks for answer btw

Comment: Honestly I don't fully understand your question then.  Can you post a pseudo code example of what you mean? This probably also why no one else an attempted an answer... it's not very clear what you are asking at all

Comment: What specific behavior? How is java regex different then php regex? Or is that what the problem is?

Comment: I think if you want to test Java regex then you will need Java. I don't think it'd be that hard to get Java on your server so not sure what the big deal is.

Comment: If it's possible to setup on another server, maybe you could send from PHP the strings you want to test to that server to validate it (overkill and annoying)

Comment: sorry for the delayed reply, I think you understood the problem. we dont have java on the server as it is a shared hosting & they dont allow java on these.